# SQL 2 Summations giving out incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im doing a query where I do 2 summations but its giving out a weird result

```
SELECT
    SUM(Details.price * Details.quantity) AS total_amount,
    SUM(Payment.amount_paid) as paid_amount
FROM
    Details,
    Invoice
LEFT JOIN
    Payment ON Invoice.id = Payment.fk_invoice_id
WHERE
    AND Invoice.id = 1
    AND Invoice.id = Details.fk_invoice_id
GROUP BY Details.fk_invoice_id;
```

what is currently happening is that lets say there are 3 rows in Payment that matches the select criteria and only 1 on details, the summation in total_amount is multiplied by 3 but the paid_amount is correct. And then lets say there are 2 items in Details that matches the criteria and in Payment just 1, paid_amount is multiplied by 2 but total_amount is correct. Any hints would be great, thanks!

Schema

```
Invoice
    id
    Name....


Details
    id
    fk_invoice_id
    name
    price
    quantity

Payment
    id
    fk_invoice_id
    amount_paid
```

More details:

I was trying to simplify my post, but just to add

Customers have many invoices

What I only have is a reference to customer, so customer.id is a foreign key in invoice, im trying to get all invoices for a particular customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want to do is sum things from DETAILS and things from PAYMENT per invoice. But you are joining all related records. So say there are 3 detail records and 2 payment records for an invoice then you multiply your detail result by 2 and your payment result by 3. You can either divide:

```
SELECT
  SUM(Details.price * Details.quantity) / GREATEST(COUNT(DISTINCT Payment.id),1) AS total_amount,
  SUM(Payment.amount_paid) / COUNT(DISTINCT Details.id) as paid_amount
FROM Details
JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.id = Details.fk_invoice_id AND Invoice.id = 1
LEFT JOIN Payment ON Invoice.id = Payment.fk_invoice_id
GROUP BY Invoice.id;
```

Or simply don't join what must not be joined. Here is one way:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(Details.price * Details.quantity) FROM Details WHERE Details.fk_invoice_id = Invoice.id) AS total_amount,
  (SELECT SUM(Payment.amount_paid) FROM Payment WHERE Payment.fk_invoice_id = Invoice.id) AS paid_amount
FROM Invoice 
WHERE id = 1;
```

Here is another, where the aggregation is done before the join. (We don't need the Invoice table anyhow, by the way. I remove it here.)

```
SELECT
  d.total_amount,
  p.paid_amount
FROM 
(
  SELECT fk_invoice_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_amount
  FROM Details 
  GROUP BY fk_invoice_id
) d ON d.fk_invoice_id = Invoice.id
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT fk_invoice_id, SUM(Payment.amount_paid) as paid_amount
  FROM Payment 
  GROUP BY fk_invoice_id
) p ON p.fk_invoice_id = Invoice.id
WHERE d.fk_invoice_id = 1;
```

As long as you are just looking for one Invoice ID, all the above statements can be simplyfied of course. For instance:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(Details.price * Details.quantity) FROM Details WHERE Details.fk_invoice_id = 1) AS total_amount,
  (SELECT SUM(Payment.amount_paid) FROM Payment WHERE Payment.fk_invoice_id = 1) AS paid_amount;
```